# Import styles into react-native

Tags: react-native, sass, styled-components

I'm stying how to import styles from other sources into react native. I see that there are options like using styled-component or even importing scss files.

Anyway, Do you have any particular recommentations?

I'm currently exploring [this option] (https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer/) but I'm getting a syntax error (Unexpected token), so I guess something in the loader is missing. Not sure.

I'd like to be able to serve styles into a react native project from an outside library.

Comment: You showed us the code that was showing the error.

Comment: I already desisted from that path. :-p
Couldn't manage to work it out.

But I still like to know your thoughts on the subject. :-)

Comment: You don't have to give up. You can make the CSS you want and use it in the React Native.

Comment: Thank you, I wont. I'll keep exploring later.